# ssh -X doesn't make X11 work

Tags: linux, ssh, xforwarding

If I ssh -X from my ubuntu machine into my work linux computer and then try to run emacs I get:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

Is there any way to fix that without being root on the work machine?

Answer (score 1):

I found many years ago that `ssh -X` no longer worked, and that I had to use `ssh -Y` instead. I don't remember the technical explanation, the "SSH for Dummies" explanation was "-X only gives you half the connection you need, -Y gives you the whole thing".

The other requirement that I usually miss when setting up a new target machine is having the `xauth` package installed on the target machine; if this isn't installed on your work machine, you will need to be root to install it, or you'll have to have someone who does have root install it for you.